# Dst tensor is not initialized

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.**

The following error occurs when training a tensorflow regression model, each time when evaluating the model on validation set

```py
val_loss = fore_model.evaluate(fore_valid_ip, fore_valid_op, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

i tried to reduce `batch_size` and `samples_per_epoch` to the minimum, the error often occurs in after the first epoch, i.e. regardless of both parameters (even with `batch_size=1`), the same error occurs when evaluating on validation data (always at epoch 1, at epoch 0 it works fine):

```
8.091448: 100%|██████████| 102400/102400 [25:12<00:00, 67.68it/s] 

136823/136823 [==============================] - 394s 3ms/step - loss: 6.9584
Epoch 0 loss 8.091447979584128 val loss 6.958434104919434

6.993011: 100%|██████████| 102400/102400 [24:58<00:00, 68.34it/s] 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[16], line 47
     45     e_loss += fore_model.train_on_batch([ip[ind] for ip in fore_train_ip], fore_train_op[ind])
     46     pbar.set_description('%f'%(e_loss/(start+1)))
---> 47 val_loss = fore_model.evaluate(fore_valid_ip, fore_valid_op, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
     48 val_losses.append(val_loss)
     49 print ('Epoch', e, 'loss', e_loss*batch_size/samples_per_epoch, 'val loss', val_loss)

File /opt/bwhpc/common/jupyter/tensorflow/2023-03-24/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/bwhpc/common/jupyter/tensorflow/2023-03-24/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:103, in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    101     dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    102 ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 103 return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

Additionally, the code ran with 2 GPUs, and it did not change the situation running with 4 GPUs. Does anyone know what went wrong and how to address the issue?